# OpenLDAP default configuration file is `/etc/ldap/slapd.d` rather than `/etc/ldap/slapd.conf`

Tags: openldap, slapd

My openldap (version 2.4.31) makes directory `/etc/ldap/slapd.d` as its default configuration files rather than `/etc/ldap/slapd.conf` as the old version does. I found it becomes more complicated to configure openldap than ever.

How should I configure openldap with slapd.d?

Comment: What's the good reasons for openldap to make slapd.d as defualt config files? How to change my `rootpw` for rootdn login ?

Answer (score 3):

No, if you understand it, it becomes pretty simple and more effective as you don't have to restart the OpenLDAP server after a config change.

As you may have noticed, `/etc/ldap/slapd.d` is a directory, not a file and it contains a set of LDIF files that together create a complete LDAP tree named `cn=config`. You modify this tree not by editing files, but by standard LDAP operations like `ldapadd` or `ldapmodify` or with graphical tools like Apache Directory Studio.

See the [manual](http://www.openldap.org/doc/admin24/guide.html#Configuring%20slapd) for more information.

Comment: You mean I don't have to care about my configrations because everything (even base dn) can be modified with client tools?

Comment: Exactly. I've no idea if renaming the base DN is possible tough in a populated tree at all, regardless of the config method.

Comment: Would you give me an example to change my backend from hdb to bdb ? And what's command to search entries from LDAP directory. `ldapsearch -x -D cn=config -W -b cn=config` alwayes told me `Invalid credentials` but I give the right password. Thank you!

Comment: Please ask this as a new question.